# Two crons doing same job in linux, which one is better

Tags: linux, cron

I have to delete all the pdf files which are more than 30 days old at 11:30 PM

The below given are the two working cronjobs in `/etc/crontab`

```
30 23 * * * root find /var/www/html/site/reports/ -name ".pdf" -type f -mtime +30 | xargs -I {} rm -f {} \;

30 23 * * * root find /var/www/html/site/reports/ ( -name ".pdf" ) -type f -mtime +30 -exec rm {} \;
```

I would like to know which one is better among the two and the reason.

Please help.

Comment: The first one doesn't handle properly filenames with weird symbols like carriage return (yes, in unix-like system including Linux it's possible to create files with names containing virtually all ASCII symbols, excluding '\0' and '/'), but it could be slightly faster due to less subprocess invocations. You could improve the first line by excplicitly using `-print0` instead of (implicit) `-print` and corresponding `xargs --null`

Comment: I would go with `find /var/www/html/site/reports/. -type f -name "*.pdf" -mtime +30 -delete` instead of either of the quoted versions...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is probably option 3. Use `-delete`.

```
30 23 * * * root find /var/www/html/site/reports/ -name '*.pdf' -type f -mtime +30 -delete
```

Both the options in the question spawn sub-shells to do the deletion work which this option avoids entirely.

The portability of `-delete` is somewhat limited. GNU `find` supports it as does FreeBSD `find` (at least according to [this man page](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?find%281%29)) but OpenBSD `find` doesn't appear to. I don't know about any others.

As user3159253 says in their comment among the first two options the first is likely somewhat faster due to requiring fewer invocations of `rm` but is not safe for filenames with newlines in them (and possibly a handful of other characters but I'm not sure).

A modification of the second option to use `-exec rm {} \+` will be better as well as it will also reduce the number of invocations of `rm` by giving it multiple files at once and may or may not be better than the first option at that point but will still not beat the option given here.

Comment: Likely, `-delete` is Linux-specific. It's worth mentioning in the answer.